# How to configure Eclipse RCP with Spring

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-rcp, spring-dm

How can I configure eclipse RCP with spring? Do I need [spring dm](http://www.springsource.org/osgi)?

Can you please show me a tutorial on how to configure spring with Eclipse RCP or Eclipse RAP?

1. How can I add spring to Eclipse RCP and just use it? How can I see the context everywhere?
2. Do I have to add something to my `Target Platform`?
3. Is there any tutorial or can you please tell me more details?

I just want to use Spring with my Eclipse RCP application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Spring DM is not the only way, but I believe it's the easiest and most complete/correct way of doing it. Prior to Spring DM, there were several projects with the goal of integrating Spring and Eclipse RCP, but none of them were very simple, or very Spring-like. I have come across a blogger who is currently writing a series of articles on integrating Spring and Eclipse RCP using Spring DM. The first 4 articles cover exactly what you need to know with examples (step 0 through step 3).

The entire list of articles is here:
http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/category/java/spring/spring-dm/

That same blogger talks about his own RCP/RAP project (where he is using Spring DM) in another set of articles. These are in French, but using Google Translate makes them useful for non-French speakers. Take a look at step 7 and step 8 here:
http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/about/dynaresume/

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog about this topic, you can find step-by-step tutorial here: http://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/step-step-spring-eclipse-rcp-applications/

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer might be helpful to anyone (like me) looking for building Spring DM, OSGI console application.

Although its been quite sometime Since Spring DM has been inherited as Gemini Blueprint, it is recommended to use Gemini Blueprint instead of Spring DM. Nevertheless, Spring DM is also a good starting point.

This tutorial is worth looking at: http://www.jroller.com/dbrosius/entry/osgi_spring_dm_w_o
It provides step by step information

**NOTE:** There is a small package-name typo in Manifest.MF file that needs to be fixed. Eclipse will flag it so it's a non-issue